# A grabber/gripper for a too tall window handle

Tags: bathroom, windows, toilet

you can see my toilet window in the image. My wife can't reach the handle, so I'm trying to come up with a solution, but, even keywords I search for is not right.

I was thinking something like a rod with a ring end that would have a cushion-like thing that would contract and expand to grip and release the handle.

To store it, we would just put it in the *windowsill*-kind of thing above the flush tank.

But, maybe I'm thinking too complex. Can you come up with something practical? Should it simply be a drilled rod with the circle filled with something like a sponge to not scratch the handle?

Thanks.

[image: the tall window and the handle]

[image: open window]

Comment: Can your wife reach the handle when standing on the toilet seat/bowl?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau that is unsafe

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not do that. Just getting a stool would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the handle does not require much force to rotate it, you could notch the handle top and bottom and use a dowel with an eyebolt screwed into the end to pull and push it into position.  Or drill a hole into the middle of the handle and use a dowel with an L-hook screwed into the end.

If the handle does require a lot of force, your best solution is probably a folding step stool.

Also, I don't see how the window opens.  Is it hinged on the bottom, and you pull the handle inward/down to open the window, and push the window up to close it?  If so, I don't see how a rod is gonna help much.

Comment: Yes, down to open, up to close. Hinged on the bottom. A rod with an end that would help with both pulling and pushing.

Comment: Got pics of the window in the open position?

Comment: Yes, added to the original post, now.

Comment: So what you need to do depends on how "closed" the window needs to be in order for the mechanism to catch.  If the window needs to be pretty tightly closed to catch, that's gonna be hard to achieve from the ground with an extension tool.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this elderly grabbers should work.

[image]

Photo from walmart. I  dont own it or work there.

Comment: Doesn't have to grip, just needs a loop that can be used to pull the handle online way or another, I think

Comment: E.G., some strong rubber tubing cut from a bicycle inner-tube attached to the end of a dowel. If the appearance was acceptable, you could leave it dangling from the handle.

Comment: I thought of this, but wouldn't you say the handle will slip from its grasp?

Answer (score 0):

If all that is required is to be able to *open* it, then a stout cord fastened on like a noose would work. It avoids a lot of the 90° struggle as anything solid over the handle would need to be angled around as the handle was turned.

[image]

Wrapped like this around the handle would resist it being pulled off as the handle reaches the down position. A little easy-to-remove glue might help.

Alternatively, if she also needs to be able to close it again, I see no real alternative than to drill the end of the handle & fasten a wand to it, capable of rotating as the handle is pushed/pulled.

[image]